# Difference between git fetch origin and git fetch ssh://originurl

Tags: git

When I list my remotes, I get:

```
> git remote -vv
origin  ssh://remote:1234/project (fetch)
origin  ssh://remote:1234/project (push)
```

If I directly put the origin url, the remote tracking branches are not getting updated.

```
 > git fetch ssh://remote:1234/project 
   From ssh://remote:1234/project 
   * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

However, if I specify "origin", remote tracking branches are updated. Why does it not update if I directly put in the origin url as above?

```
> git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 19, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (12/12)
remote: Total 12 (delta 2), reused 12 (delta 2)
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
From ssh://remote:1234/project 
   1dd995c..32a2ef5  branchA/somename -> origin/branchA/somename 
 * [new branch]      branchB/somename -> origin/branchB/somename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I directly put the origin url, the remote tracking branches are not getting updated ...

The reason for this is trivially simple: Git is stupid. :-)

More seriously, with one command, you are saying to Git: *Use the name Fred, or Remote1234, or—wait, I know, this is the* best name ever: `origin`!  *Anyway, as I was saying, use that name, fetch some stuff, and remember it for me.*

With the other command, you are saying: *Go to this URL, fetch some stuff, and remember it for me.*

Under what *name* shall Git remember these things?

When you say "using the name `origin`", Git has a really good name to use.  It sticks `origin/` in front of each name:

```
   1dd995c..32a2ef5  branchA/somename -> origin/branchA/somename 
 * [new branch]      branchB/somename -> origin/branchB/somename
```

When you give Git just a plain URL, it has no good name, so it falls back on the method it used decades ago, back before "remotes" were invented: it shoves all the information in a file named `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This is why it says:

```
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

(You can stop here if you like.  The section below is not necessary for the simple answer.  The rest is more about *how Git achieves this*, than what the general *idea* is.  The *how* part has a bunch of [knock-on effects](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knock-on) if you start fiddling with all of Git's [little turney knobs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_-SkRA6AjM).)

#### That's a nice, memorable explanation, but it hides a deeper truth

There is an important, yet somewhat obscure, difference that your question exposes.  You've shown it above, and I have quoted it: the fetch using `origin` updated *two* remote-tracking branches, yet the fetch using a raw URL updated or created only *one* entry in the `FETCH_HEAD` file.

The reason for this is buried here in [the `git fetch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), under the "confgured remote-tracking branches" section:

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```
>
> When `git fetch` is run without specifying what branches and/or tags
>    to fetch on the command line, e.g. `git fetch origin` or `git fetch`,
>    `remote.<repository>.fetch` values are used as the refspecs—they
>    specify which refs to fetch and which local refs to update. The
>    example above will fetch all branches that exist in the origin
>    (i.e. any ref that matches the left-hand side of the value,
>    `refs/heads/*`) and update the corresponding remote-tracking branches
>    in the `refs/remotes/origin/*` hierarchy.

That is, your Git determines *which names to fetch* (and consequently which *commits* to obtain from the other Git) using `remote.origin.fetch`, which you can show by running:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

(we need `--get-all` as there may be more than one such configuration line; we want all of them, not just the last one, which plain `--get` would show us).  Hence, giving Git the name `Fred` or `remote1234` or, more commonly, `origin`, tells Git *what to fetch by default*, as well as *how to rename the result* (i.e., to stick `origin/` in front).  Changing the `remote.origin.fetch` line, or adding additional lines, changes the default set of "what to fetch" and/or the "how to rename the result".

These are less relevant, but not entirely *ir*relevant, if you supply refspecs (such as branch names) on the command line:

```
git fetch origin foobranch 'refs/notes/*:refs/notes/origin/*'
```

for instance.  Here, you have explicitly told Git *what to fetch*, overriding `remote.origin.fetch`.  But if you do not tell Git what to fetch, it looks for the named-remote's `remote.origin.fetch` setting—and if you use a raw URL, instead of a remote name like `origin`, there is no place to look, so you get yet another historical backup: it just brings over whatever it finds under the other Git's `HEAD`.

(There is more in the documentation, such as the description of `--refmap`.  Study it for additional useless arcane Git knowledge. :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Fetch gets commits, updates `FETCH_HEAD` (the list of everything it fetched), and additionally updates any local refs you specify. When you fetch a remote, it looks up the url and refs in the config.

Your bare-url fetch didn't specify any refs to update, so it only updated `FETCH_HEAD`.

You specify which refs to fetch and/or update with a "refspec", and each remote has a configured default refspec to go with the url, generally `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote/*`.

I have an alias for `git config --get-regexp` that supplies a default wildcard, `git config --global alias.gr '!f() { git config --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f'` (and another one, `grl`, that adds the `--local` switch), with that you can

```
git gr origin
```

to see any "origin"-related configs.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, git fetch url should work.If not these are things worth to check.

*Sidenote* : SSH doesn't work with an HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

**Here is the detailed answer about git fetch:**

- git fetch,it fetches the remote tracking branches from the reposistery, it fetches all latest branches.
- `git fetch` can fetch from either a single named repository or URL, or from several repositories at once if  is given and there is a remotes. entry in the configuration file.
- When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch.
- It copies all branches from the remote refs/heads/ namespace and stores them to the local refs/remotes/origin/ namespace, unless the branch..

**Peek at a remote’s branch, without configuring the remote in your local repository:**

```
$ git fetch git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git maint
$ git log FETCH_HEAD
```

[Please do check the usage of GIT URLS:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a)

**The following syntaxes may be used with them:**

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

or

```
ssh://username@url.com/username/workfolder
```

In your case,you can check the config file:

Perhaps worth looking at the remote.origin.fetch setting, if its correct then try ssh url with username.

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```